# Can't get any information from the url

Tags: php, android, json

I can't debug my program with getting information from my PHP. It is working in a seperated apk but when I set up it with a button, this is the error I always get.

"ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url"

so here is my code using JSON

```
package net.example.ab;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AbJasonActivity extends Activity {

     private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // URL to get contacts JSON
        private static String url = "http://192.168.2.9/android_connect/ivpcms.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_LISTS= "records_tbl";
        private static final String TAG_RECORDS = "rec_id";
        private static final String TAG_PHYSICIAN = "phy_id";
        private static final String TAG_PATIENT = "pat_id";
        private static final String TAG_VOLUME = "vol_id";
        private static final String TAG_DROP = "dro_id";
        private static final String TAG_MINUTES = "rec_minutes";
        private static final String TAG_DPM = "dpm";

        TextView test;



        // contacts JSONArray
        JSONArray lists = null;

        // Hashmap for ListView


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.lol);

            test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
            test.setText(""+ lists);


         // Calling async task to get json
            new GetDoctors().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetDoctors extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AbJasonActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    lists = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_LISTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts

                        JSONObject c = lists.getJSONObject(0);

                        String rec_id = c.getString(TAG_RECORDS);
                        String phy_id = c.getString(TAG_PHYSICIAN);
                        String pat_id = c.getString(TAG_PATIENT);
                        String vol_id = c.getString(TAG_VOLUME);
                        String dro_id = c.getString(TAG_DROP);
                        String rec_minutes = c.getString(TAG_MINUTES);
                        double dpm = c.getDouble(TAG_DPM);
                        String dpm2 = String.valueOf(dpm);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> doctor = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        doctor.put(TAG_RECORDS, rec_id);
                        doctor.put(TAG_PHYSICIAN, phy_id);
                        doctor.put(TAG_PATIENT, pat_id);
                        doctor.put(TAG_VOLUME, vol_id);
                        doctor.put(TAG_DROP, dro_id);
                        doctor.put(TAG_MINUTES, rec_minutes);
                        doctor.put(TAG_DPM, dpm2);



                        // adding contact to contact list


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

        }

    }

}
```

my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Main ListView 
             Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
        -->
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/test"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/testing" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the code of my button which is working fine

```
    private void setupMessageButtonAb() {
        // 1. for the button

        Button messageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ab);

        //2. set click listener

        messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(AB, "You've chosen Dr. Melegrito!");
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,
                        "You've chosen Dr. Melegrito",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();



                startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, AbJasonActivity.class));

            }
        });

    }`
```

**PS**: since my JSON code is running with another apk and webserver is running with correct IP add of it. I dont know what is my error. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: did you add the internet permission?

Comment: oh. I forgot. thanks @Coderji :)